# follow external process in c # and show message

Tags: c#, winforms

Reviewing the answers, I will be more detailed when starting the process.start (); in the task manager a process called ffmpeg.exe is generated, this is the one that performs the cut and leaves it in the network folder. I need to show a messagebox.show (cut finally); to indicate to the person who continues to generate different cuts can review the finished cut

```
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = $@"/k ffmpeg.exe {arguments}";
           
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
```

this ffmpeg.exe process is created

[image]

then it disappears from the task manager when the cut finished successfully, I want to show a messagebox.show (); indicating that it was cut to review

Comment: Why you start cmd.exe for start ffmpeg? Why not start ffmpeg with parameters?

Comment: yep for star ffmpeg and ffmpeg arguments receive parametres to cut video file

Comment: I mean you can start like this `startInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe"; startInfo.Arguments = arguments;`

Comment: I need to follow the process that ffmpeg started and when I finish cutting the video, indicate by messabox.show (I finish);

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code right after starting the process:

```
            process.WaitForExit();
```

Then, your application will wait for FFmpeg's task to get completed.

** Update: For preventing the application to get frozen, you have 2 options.

1. You can run the process starter in a separated thread:

   ```
         bool taskFinished=false;   //define a boolean to use that for checking if the process finished.
        new Task(() =>
        {
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = $@"/k ffmpeg.exe {arguments}";

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();       
        taskFinished=true;     
        }).Start();
   ```

Do note that, if you want to run the process in a separated task as above, the application also will go to the next line even if the process is running. For managing this, you'll need to define a boolean to use that for checking if the process is finished.

2. You can use an event for checking if the process ended.
   The code will be like this:

   ```
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = $@"/k ffmpeg.exe {arguments}";

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true; //add this
        process.Exited += new EventHandler(ProcessExited); //define an event that will be triggered after process get exited.

        process.Start();

        void ProcessExited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        // Write the codes that you want to get executed after the process is finished/exited.
        }
   ```

Comment: This locks the program until the correct hack finishes, but how do I bypass the crash and display a message when finished?

Comment: Run it on a separate thread. Dont forget to use the right `SynchronizationContext` when you want show an msgbox from that thread!

Comment: I'm a bit new, I can't understand you, I only understood using the await task delay

Comment: Updated the answer. I added two solutions for managing app's freezing.

Comment: it works for the process that is generated as an event from the cut, but it does not work to follow the ffmpeg.exe and define if I finish or not

Comment: When FFmpeg finishes its task, it exits, so the "Exit" event will be triggered right after FFmpeg finishes the task.If you're doing several tasks in one FFmpeg process, and you want to know if a specific task is finished, I'd recommend you separate the tasks then you'll know which task is finished. So, for instance, if you're cutting a video and merging the videos in one process, you can separate the processes and in the first step cut the video via one process, then in the second step, merge the videos via a different process.

Comment: mas de 1 año despues, ahora si entiendo que quisite decir me funciono muchas Gracias